# Reverse Expanding Direction of after/before psuedo element

Tags: html, css, styles

**What I am doing:** Have images going down a column odd divs with float left and right divs float right.
It all works fine, but I am having a bit of trouble with the sizing of the psuedo classes and such.
**Issue in a nutshell:** I have the psuedo element :after present information on hover of one of the images and with width:auto; it is fine and expands from the left as it should and text length no issue. Though when trying to do the same but for the opposite side, the text length will often overlap the image itself as it expands from the left.
**Question:** How do I change the direction of expansion of the psuedo element :after or :before (doesn't matter which) to expand auto from right to left rather than the default left to right with the width being auto.
**Example of the issue here** https://jsfiddle.net/fd0p537r/

```
.outer{display:inline-block;width:240px;background-color:Blue;}
.outer div{background-color:Red;margin:10px 50px;width:3em;height:3em;}
.outer div:after{visibility:hidden;position:absolute;width:auto;line-height:30px;background-color:cadetblue;}
.outer div:hover:after{visibility:visible;}
.outer div:nth-child(odd){float:left;}
.outer div:nth-child(even){float:right;}
.outer div:nth-child(odd):after{margin-left:3em;}
.outer div:nth-child(even):after{margin-left:-3em;}
.outer div:before{visibility:hidden;position:absolute;width:auto;line-height:30px;background-color:cadetblue;}
.outer div:hover:before{visibility:visible;}
.one:after{content:"oneoneoneone";}
.two:after{content:"Two";}
.three:after{content:"Three";}
.four:after{content:"FourFourFour";}



<div class="outer">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using `:before`, [the `ch` measurement](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/#article-header-id-11), a monospace font and `margin-left`

Making these changes at the end of your fiddle's CSS

```
/* use a monospace font */
.one, .two, .three, .four { font-family: Consolas, monospace; }

.one:after{content:"oneoneoneone";}

/* place the content before and */
/* make use of the monospace */
.two:before{content:"Two"; margin-left: -3ch }

.three:after{content:"Three";}

/* place the content before and */
/* make use of the monospace */
.four:before{content:"FourFourFour"; margin-left: -12ch }
```

works, but is perhaps not as dynamic a solution as you'd like.

Comment: When the before/after element is absolute positioned, it bases itself off where the parent div begins in this case the first line of the text. Your solution requires you to specify the width of the div rather than it being automatic. The question wasn't to make it look right but rather how to change the direction of the font so the text could go right to left without a specific margin for each to be specified. This makes it so I can use as many or as few characters as I choose without needing to change the margin or width or anything else | P.S. I didn't know about the ch measurement thanks :D

Comment: If the pseudo element content is being generated dynamically, so is the CSS, and during that generation, the content length can be easily established and added to the rule. If the content is not being dynamically generated, this solution works just fine. Anyhoo, do with it what you will.